# PHP Form Submit and anchor back where it was

Tags: php, anchor, form-submit

I have on my page a dataTable with tons of rows. Each row has an id, name, surname and an action column. In the action column there is a textarea where you can add a comment and a button that submits that comment. When I submit the comment I want the page to position itself where it was, but I cannot figure it out how. Any ideas?

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<form method='post' action='saveComment.php#position_".$row['id']."'>";
    echo "<td hidden><input hidden name='id' readonly value=" . $row['id'] . " /></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Comment'/></td>";
    echo "<a id='position_".$row['id']."'></a>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

I tried passing the id of the current row to the script that saves the comment and it does pass the value, after which it should position it back where it was, but it doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: The easiest way would be to implement the submission in AJAX - then the page does not reload and you do not need to worry about the position change.

Comment: I tried it with ajax, but because I never used it I'm not really experienced with it. Do you have any tutorials? I found a few, tried, but it didn't work...and this seems quite like an easy thing to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how it works with anchors! The problem was that I didn't pass the id in the saveComment.php script when redirecting back to the original page.

Code in the page where the form is:

```
if ($_POST['submit']){
$id=$_POST["id"];   
header('Refresh: 0.5; URL=originalPage.php#position_' . $id);
//...rest of code goes here...
}
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

use Ajax to submit the form, and on success:

```
window.location = 'saveComment.php#position_<? echo $row['id']; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<a name='position_".$row['id']."'></a>
```

instead of

```
<a id='position_".$row['id']."'></a>
```